# How can I use a static library built using Code Blocks in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have a `.a` static library file that i have created using Code Blocks. It contains the function definition of a function that adds two numbers. I want to use this library in Android using NDK. I want to know how this can be done in detail. I am beginner at this, and therefore step-by-step explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile your static library for Android using the NDK first. A static lib compiled for a Linux system will certainly not work (different C and system libraries).

Plus, Android runs on 7 different architectures as of now, so if you want to properly support all of them, you should end up with 7 different versions of your `.a` static library.

You can then reference your library from another NDK module (`.so` files) that you can load from an Android application. Please follow the NDK documentation to see how this works, and samples here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk